# Show different footer if the total amount of published posts is greater than one in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to say if the number of published posts is only one, get_footer();... but.. if the number of published posts is greater than one, get_footer('single')..

This is my current code that doesn't seem to work:

```
<?php

 $count_posts = wp_count_posts();

  if($count_posts = 1){
     get_footer();
 } else if($count_posts > 1) {
     get_footer('single');
 }

?>
```

Comment: Can you show us your var_dump($count_posts) first?

Comment: I'll have to look that up.  I don't even know what that is because I'm new to Wordpress.

Comment: `wp_count_posts()` returns an object not an integer value unless I read it wrong.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts.  Also like @Brendan said, shouldn't you have the `get_footer('single')` if `$count_posts == 1` and not in the else if block?

Comment: As you can see here, footer-single.php has a pagination to toggle between posts.  footer.php has no pagination.  If there is only one post published, you can't toggle between posts since only one exists.  http://matthewkosloski.me/footer-single.txt & http://matthewkosloski.me/footer.txt

Comment: @MattKnowsTech Unfortunately, I'm not a Wordpress guy. I guess I could eventually figure it out, but then my wife'd kill me, then.... where am I gonna sleep? I doubt the dog's gonna wanna share his sleeping quarters, as in **dog house**. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` performs an assignment, so this:

```
if($count_posts = 1){
```

... is basically the same as this:

```
$count_posts = 1;
if($count_posts) {
```

Most likely you wanted to do a comparison instead of an assignment:

```
if($count_posts == 1){
```

Comment: @MattKnowsTech Define "doesn't seem to work"? Is the remaining problem that you should be doing `get_footer('single')` in the first case, not the second? Beyond that, I'd need to see the source for `get_footer`.

Comment: Here is footer-single: http://www.matthewkosloski.me/footer-single.txt and the footer:  http://www.matthewkosloski.me/footer.txt          There is a pagination on footer-single that I don't want displayed if there is only one post.

Comment: @MattKnowsTech Then try `===`. E.g. `if($count_posts === 1){`

Comment: Nah, that doesn't work.  If I do that, the footer doesn't even render. haha

Comment: @MattKnowsTech Oh well, I tried. Gawd, one figures if 2 boulders doesn't bring down that wall, maybe a **3rd will** ;-)

Comment: @MattKnowsTech You're welcome. Have you tried going in the other direction, instead of `if posts are more than`, doing `if posts are less then` or `do not equal`? Maybe that server of yours needs a good shot of `reverse psychology`!

Comment: I don't think that would do much, that's saying if there are 0 posts do something haha

Comment: I think the main problem is: wp_count_posts(); isn't the correct thingy to use.  Sorry, I have NO idea what to call that. :P

Comment: @MattKnowsTech Try `echo`ing the value to see if it returns what you expect. And put some `echo`s in your `if`/`else` statement to see if it takes the branch you expect.

Comment: @MattKnowsTech Is the problem that [`get_footer`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer) is looking for `footer-single.php`, but you only gave it `footer-single.txt`?

Comment: @MattKnowsTech From what I found on a similar note, `if( $published_posts >= 3 ) {`. Have you tried the `>= 1` or something close to that? I found it here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/if-blog-has-more-than-x-posts-display-link

Comment: I gave it in a .txt file to show you my code haha.  They're both called footer.php and footer-single.php in my theme folder.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help, including Fred! :)  I got it! I put the following in single.php: 

<?php
$count_posts = wp_count_posts();
$published_posts = $count_posts->publish;
if( $published_posts <= 1 ) {
 get_footer();
} else if($published_posts > 1) {
 get_footer('single');
}
?>

Comment: Sorry it's hard to read, I can't get the 'code' thing to work.

Comment: @MattKnowsTech Heyyyy right on, glad to hear it! Way to go ;-) cheers (you're welcome) (Now I just need to throw my dog out his house... that I ahem...built) hehe

Comment: @MattKnowsTech You should now post it as an **answer**.

Comment: @MattKnowsTech You can simplify that to an `if`/`else` instead of `if`/`else if`.